# High CPU when Windows service queue is stored in a database

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I have implemented a Windows service with a queue that is stored in a database table.

I have a table called `MyQueue` and each row of this table specifies a task for the Windows Service. When the task is completed the row is marked with a special flag which means that this task has been completed.

My Windows service works in the following way:

```
while(true)
{
     // get the first row from MyQueue that is not yet marked

     // complete the task from the row

     // mark the row as completed
}
```

This design works, but as I use `while(true)` it continuously sends requests to the database to check if there are any new rows and this causes CPU usage to rise higher than 60%.

Is there a more effective way to implement a queue stored in a database table?

Comment: What's adding rows to MyQueue? Can you not also have it alert your service?

Answer (score 0):

You could use SqlTableDependency

Answer (score 0):

You can control the cpu usage by adding some sleep (as per work load) in the current thread when no data found in Queue.

```
while(true)
 {
    // get the first row from MyQueue that is not yet marked
    if(MyQueue.Count == 0)
    {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
          continue;
    }

     // complete the task from the row

      // mark the row as completed
}
```